# How to set up JDBC Application with Oracle RDBMS access?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jdbc

I need to set up a development environment that uses the JDBC Application and can access the Oracle RDBMS.

So far, I've installed Java DB and, using Eclipse, tried to create a new database connection to an oracle database.  It doesn't work.

Can anyone help me set up everything I need to create a database and issue SQL scripts to it?  I've tried looking for tutorials online but the only ones I've found used the MySQL DB instead of the Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: If you've only found the MySQL tutorials out of all the possible databases that are available, you're not looking hard enough. The general idea is also pretty much the same for all databases, only the driver and connection properties differ.

Answer (score 1):

JavaDB is not what you want; it's the former Derby dbms for embedded applications, and is a *substitute for*, not a *connection to*, an Oracle database.

What you need is the [Oracle JDBC Driver package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html), which provides the tools for a Java application to connect to an Oracle 12c (or earlier) database the same as it would connect to a MySQL or PostgreSQL database.

Hope that helps.